# How to redirect to other page using submit button

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am writing a view that retrieve an answer from game2.html, check the answer; if the answer is correct, the view will redirect user to correct.html, if the answer is incorrect, then user will be redirected to incorrect.html.

The problem now is after clicking the submit button, user won't be redirected. But the score is updated.

After I clicked submit button the url will change from http://localhost:8000/game2/ to http://localhost:8000/game2/?ans2=4&game2Answer=Submit instead of redirect to correct.html or incorrect.html

I guess it might be the problem of my submit button that doesn't trigger the redirect function, or it is the problem of the way I write redirect function in views, as the score is actually updated if the answer is correct.

So, how can i fix it to make it able to redirect to either correct.html or incorrect.html after going into the if-else statement.

**morse_logs/views.py**

```
@login_required()
def game2(request):
    """The Game2 page"""
    if request.user and not request.user.is_anonymous:
        user = request.user

    def verifyGame2(val1):
        user_score, created = userScore.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        if val1 == 4:
            # user's score declared in model increase 5points
            # display correct and 5 points added to user
            user_score.score += 5
            user_score.save()
            return redirect('morse_logs:incorrect')
        else:
            # user's score declared in model has no point
            # display incorrect and 0 point added to user
            return redirect('morse_logs:incorrect')


    ans2 = request.GET.get('ans2', '')
    if ans2 == '':
        ans2 = 0

    verifyGame2(int(ans2))

    return render(request, 'morse_logs/game2.html')
```

**game2.html**

```
{% extends "morse_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <title>GAME 2</title>
<div>
    <h1>GAME 2</h1>
    <h2>2 + 2 = ?</h2>
    <form action="" method="post" >
        <input type="number" id="ans1" name="ans1"/><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="game1Answer"/>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**morse_logs/correct.html**

```
{% extends "morse_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <title>Correct!</title>
<div>
    <h1>Congratulations! Your answer is CORRECT!</h1>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**morse_logs/incorrect.html**

```
{% extends "morse_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <title>Inorrect...</title>
<div>
    <h1>Unfortunately! Your answer is Incorrect!</h1>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**morse_logs/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from morse_logs import views

app_name = 'morse_logs'

urlpatterns = [
    #The path() function is passed four arguments, two required: route and view, and two optional: kwargs, and name.
    # Home Page
    path(r'', views.index, name='index'),
    # Page that shows all topics
    path(r'topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    path(r'cipher/', views.cipher, name='cipher'),
    path(r'decipher/', views.decipher, name='decipher'),
    path(r'tutorialIndex/', views.tutorialIndex, name='tutorialIndex'),
    path(r'gameDirectory/', views.gameDirectory, name='gameDirectory'),
    path(r'game1/', views.game1, name='game1'),
    path(r'game2/', views.game2, name='game2'),
    path(r'correct/', views.correct, name='correct'),
    path(r'incorrect/', views.incorrect, name='incorrect'),
]
```

Comment: Replace `redirect('morse_logs:incorrect.html')` with `redirect('incorrect')`. Similar changes for `redirect('morse_logs:correct.html')`.

Comment: now it's saying page not found 404

Comment: Do you have urls configured for `incorrect` and `correct` views? Add your urls.py to question.

Comment: Yes I do have it

Comment: For which URL, Django is returning 404? And are you able to access that url directly (like from browser)?

Comment: When I access game2.html, then it says page not found

Comment: If I access http://localhost:8000/incorrect/, it is okay. And if I click the link of game2 in gameDirectory.html, it will have page not found with url http://localhost:8000/game2/incorrect/

Comment: Seems you'll have to put complete path of view in `redirect`. Can you try `redirect(morse_logs.views.incorrect)` in place of `redirect('incorrect')`. It should work, but if it doesn't can you please try `redirect('morse_logs:incorrect')`.

Comment: sorry but it still doesn't work, i think it's because whenever I click game2, it will directly go into else statement. And, if i access localhost:8000/incorrect.html directly, it is okay.

Comment: Now, once i click the link game2 from gameDirectory.html, it will show me page not found and with url http://localhost:8000/game2/morse_logs.views.incorrect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211702/discussion-between-din-and-narendra-choudhary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I changed the template form method from "GET" to "POST" and add {% csrf_token %}.

Secondly, I changed the view into 2 parts:

1st part is when user first enter game2.html(GET request), it will render game2.html to user.

2nd part is basically what I have done before, but this time I added a case that respond to user's POST request, and from there to do redirections to either correct.html or incorrect.html

**game2.html**

```
{% extends "morse_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <title>GAME 2</title>
<div>
    <h1>GAME 2</h1>
    <h2>2 + 2 = ?</h2>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="number" id="ans2" name="ans2"/><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required()
def game2(request):
    """The Game2 page"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'morse_logs/game2.html')
    elif request.method == "POST":
        if request.user and not request.user.is_anonymous:
            user = request.user

        user_score, created = userScore.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        ans2 = request.POST.get('ans2', '') #fetch the POST data from template
        if ans2 == '':
            ans2 = 0

        ans2 = int(ans2)
        if ans2 == 4:
            # user's score declared in model increase 5points
            # display correct and 5 points added to user
            user_score.score += 5
            user_score.save()
            return redirect(reverse('morse_logs:correct'))
        else:
            # user's score declared in model has no point
            # display incorrect and 0 point added to user
            return redirect(reverse('morse_logs:incorrect'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your

> redirect('morse_logs:incorrect.html')

to

> redirect('url_name')

And also remove the app_name if you are using django version >2.0

Comment: But in my another view, I did this: return redirect('morse_logs:index'), it also works, I am thinking is it the problem of my game2.html, that how I retrieve the answer isn't correct, or the way I redirect the page is incorrect

Comment: in your form in template add action="." There is no (.) or just remove the action form the form tag

Comment: Does other url works ?? and what is the final url of the incorrect/correct

Comment: other url works, i think one of the problem now is whenever i click the link of game2 from gameDirectory.html, it will automatically go to else case in views, and the url becomes http://localhost:8000/game2/incorrect, instead of http://localhost:8000/incorrect.html